# Yii2: Saving return values of function value to Database

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a function in my model PatientDetail.php.

This function is working well and returning the desired value, but I am not able to save the same in database.

```
public function getRoomCategory(){
     $model = \app\models\RoomCategory::find('id')
     ->innerJoin('room_charges','room_charges.room_category=room_category.id')
     ->innerjoin('patient_detail', 'room_charges.id = patient_detail.bed_type')               
     ->Where(['patient_detail.id'=> $this->id])->one();

     return $model;

   }
```

I have a field/Column in the model as 'room_category' and I want to save the return value of the function `getRoomCategory` in the Database.

I have tried to create the function with the same name like `getroom_category(){}`, but then I am not getting any value in the form field in my _form.php

I have also tried in my controller like:

```
if(isset($_POST['RoomCategory'])){
                $RoomCategory = $_POST['RoomCategory'];

            $model->room_category=$RoomCategory;
            $model->save();
            }
```

What is the best way to save the calculated value to the database?
Thank for your valuable guidance.

Comment: What is the logic behind this? Because according to your code, it looks like `room_category` should be a relation.

Comment: I have created a function in Model as above `getRoomCategory` and included that in my _form as `<?= $form->field($model, 'RoomCategory')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>` I have a field `room_category` which I want to be saved in DB with the value returned by function `getRoomCategory`

Comment: Trace:  ~if($model->validate()){
            $model->save(); 
        }else{
            var_dump($model->errors);
        }~

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **rules validation** of the model is not allowing you to save it so If u want to save it without the validation you can do like this :

```
if(isset($_POST['RoomCategory'])){

   $RoomCategory = $_POST['RoomCategory'];

   $model->room_category=$RoomCategory;
   $model->save(false);
        }
```